# Using Azure App Configuration for dynamic configuration in a microservice environment

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-app-configuration

I have tried to find out how I can notify multiple microservice (MS) instances via eventdriven approach  if their Azure App Configuration values are changed. I have found that I via Eventgrid can listen on changes in Azure App Configuration but I don't find any built in method to distribute event to multiple instances (many MS instances)... I can choose webhook but then it will be to one instance, I can choose other eventdriven approaches as Event Hub but then I have to setup that and I wonder what is best practice for this? I don't want each MS to poll for changes rather to be notified and receive what has been changed or is there a better built in approach/strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For push-based configuration updates from Azure App Configuration, the suggested approach is to forward events to a Service Bus Topic. Azure Service Bus SDK provides [RegisterMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient.registermessagehandler) method that allows clients to register a message handler that would be triggered for every message recieved in the topic. Each instance of the microservice could set up a subscription to this Service Bus Topic and register a message handler during service initialization to receive configuration updates.

The instructions to set up a service bus topic can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-topics-subscriptions-portal). Details on the protocols available to subscribe to service bus topics and the required firewall configuration can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq#what-ports-do-i-need-to-open-on-the-firewall). Since a single topic can support up to 2000 subscriptions, this approach would allow up to 2000 service instances.

Comment: Another question...For each MS-instance do I need to create a new unique subscriber programmaticly for given instance or is there a built in mechanism for one-to-many-messaging

Comment: Each microservice instance needs to create its own subscription programmatically. This is the supported way for multiple subscribers to consume messages from a service bus topic.